# Allow users to search HTML by real-time JavaScript queryselector queries

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a pure HTML Table, what I would like to do is allow the User to query the table via JavaScript. The structure is as follows:

1. A simple table (depicted here: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tIuBL)
2. Provide a textarea or use a Library like Monaco editor to allow the user to write up JS QuerySelector queries.
3. Return the modified results to the User.

I am aware of security concerns, but this is a local static generated list of HTML files.

What I am unclear is;

1. Are there libraries that can do this already? I've found some "live-editors" that allow JavaScript to be executed, but I haven't been successful in replicating the results to modify the Table contents only. What ends up happening is that the whole page seems to get malformed when a user executes JS.
2. Is there another way to let users write-up JavaScript QuerySelector script to "play" with the exported tables?

Table structure:

```
<table class="order-table table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td>99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jane Vanda</td>
                <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
                <td>9876543210</td>
                <td>349</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
                <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
                <td>6754328901</td>
                <td>199</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Just get the textarea input with `document.getElementById("myTextarea").value` and put it in a querySelector.

Answer (score 0):

You can just offer a normal textarea for users to type in the queries.

Use .value to get the typed in text as a String.

The use the string as an argument for document.querySelectorAll.

[edited to incorporate nilsf comment]

Comment: I don't think that eval would be necessary here.

Comment: ah, you're right, we only need the string as an argument for document.querySelectorAll